# <= todays date in the same month i

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Hi Im trying to return all values from a date/time field which are in the same month but <= todays date

I've tried

```
Month(<=Now())   
Month(<=Date())
```

into an expression field within the query builder

which looks like this
    Month([followupdate])

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also just use this criteria for *followupdate*:

```
Between DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 1) And Date()
```

indeed if you have an index on *followupdate*.

Comment: Yes, this is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need two criteria (in two criteria columns):

```
Month([followupdate]) = Month(Date())
AND
[followupdate] <= Date()
```